# Access multiple sites with same login credentials?

Tags: php

**Problem Statement**

How to allow users having login credentials of one site/domain to login into another site/domain with the same login credentials.

**For example**

A person having two websites. let say xyz.com which have many users and abc.com is the new one so the person wants to allow the existing user of xyz.com to access the site abc.com with the same login credentials as xyz.com or vice-versa.

**Note:** abc.com is developed in WordPress and xyz.com is in Laravel.

**Please suggest what are the possible ways to achieve this functionality?**

Comment: use the same users table to authenticate on both site

Comment: Exactly as @RAUSHANKUMAR said, use same users table for both sites if u have used another database for othersite import the users table from previous one to this one.

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR , I can't agree with your statement as it would end with a bad design: 2 apps using the same database. It is rarely a good idea to share:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105786/should-i-use-one-database-per-application-or-share-a-single-database-amongst-mul

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer yeah i am agree with your comments, it may create bottleneck and some serious maintenance issues, but for small applications it would be fine

Comment: (If you have control over both sites)  NO need to Bring Whole Database, or Whole table to the second one as the comments above implied. Get ONLY the authentication-related fields from the First one,  usually, username, password and any additional stuff, and update the second site's user table's corresponding fields..

Comment: wordpress or php has NO significance here. Drawing data from one database table and insert/update into another is the gist of it. Of course there could be slight syntax differences. But if you are developing in both, you might be aware of those differences...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know why this guy has been downvoted so much but I'll take my time to answer:

You should not consider sharing the databse. Not directly at least.
You can take a look at this post to understand why: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105786/should-i-use-one-database-per-application-or-share-a-single-database-amongst-mul

Accepted Answer:

> Space is cheap these days, so I'd advise to use one database per
>   application.
>
> Sharing one database for amongst multiple applications has some
>   serious disadvantages:
>
> The more applications use the same database, the more likely it is
>   that you hit performance bottlenecks and that you can't easily scale
>   the load as desired. SQL Databases don't really scale. You can buy
>   bigger machines but they do not scale well in clusters!
>
> Maintenance and development costs can increase: Development is harder
>   if an application needs to use database structures which aren't suited
>   for the task at hand but have to be used as they are already present.
>   It's also likely that adjustments of one application will have side
>   effects on other applications ("why is there such an unecessary
>   trigger??!"/"We don't need that data anymore!"). It's already hard
>   with one database for a single application, when the developers
>   don't/can't know all the use-cases.
>
> Administration becomes harder: Which object belongs to which
>   application? Chaos rising. Where do I have to look for my data? Which
>   user is allowed to interact with which objects? What can I grant whom?
>
> Upgrading: You'll need a version that is the lowest common denominator
>   for all applications using it. That means that certain applications
>   won't be able to use powerful features. You'll have to stick with
>   older versions. It also increases development costs a bit.
>
> Concurrency: Can you really be sure that there're no chronological
>   dependencies between processes? What if one application modifies data
>   that is outdated or should've been altered by another application
>   first? What about different applications working on the same tables
>   concurrently?
>
> Compared to that, data imports/ETL-processes are almost always pretty
>   straightforward and simple. Load the data as often as you need to,
>   space is cheap. You can account for scalability for each application
>   independently, adjust and tweak the structures as you need them and
>   there won't be concurrency issues. Side effects can be traced much
>   easier, too.
>
> Edit: I'd like to point out, though, that as @Saeed mentioned, if you
>   can encapsulate data manipulations in a service which is commonly
>   available, then it's easier to share one database with multiple
>   applications. As long as you don't need raw access that is a very good
>   approach.

This said, both of your websites should not share their domain/databases. But it does not mean that one site can't consume services provided by the other. That would actually be a good idea.

Let say someone is on xyz.com and wants to access to abc.com. This user will have 2 possibilities:

- create a new account
- connect with xyz.com credentials.

In second case, which is the one we are interested in, abc.com will consume a services exposed by xyz.com in order to know if the user can connect or not.

If xyz.com responds positivly to the request, then you can consider the user as logged in. 
Then you can choose to persist the user in abc.com database in order to avoid calling xyz.com service the next time the user will want to connect. It also allows abc.com to have kind of a copy of xyz.com user which can be enriched with abc.com

For more valuable and precise answer about your problem, I suggest you to go on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ which is probably a better place to ask your question ;)